# Why can't I use an inline expression in sp_addextendedproperty but I can use a variable?

Tags: sql-server, extended-properties

When I run this T-SQL on a SQL Server 2016 database with compatibility level 130 I get an error:

```
DECLARE @myVariable int = 4;

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty
    @name = N'MyExtendedProperty',
    @value = FORMAT( @myVariable, 'd', 'en-US' ), 
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name=N'dbo',
    @level1type = N'TABLE' , @level1name=N'MyTable';
```

The error message is below, and SSMS highlights the use of `@myVariable` within the `FORMAT` function call:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near '@myVariable'

But if I use an intermediate variable the SQL runs successfully:

```
DECLARE @myVariable int = 4;

DECLARE @myVariableText nvarchar(10) = FORMAT( @myVariable, 'd', 'en-US' )

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty
    @name = N'MyExtendedProperty',
    @value = @myVariableText, 
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name=N'dbo',
    @level1type = N'TABLE' , @level1name=N'MyTable';
```

I did wonder if `FORMAT` or `sp_addextendedproperty` is a *magical* function like `RAISERROR` which requires the first argument to be a string literal (no expressions allowed) but the documentation for `sp_addextendedproperty` does not mention any restrictions on the `@value` parameter:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addextendedproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
>
> `[ @value= ] { 'value'}`
>
> Is the value to be associated with the property. value is `sql_variant`, with a default of NULL. The size of value cannot be more than 7,500 bytes.

Comment: T-SQL is a crufty language that often surprises people with the lack of orthogonality between some features (here, the fact that expressions can't be used in all the places that variables or literals can)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass values to a stored procedure, you can only pass values, and stored procedures do not allow expressions to be evaluated.

```
exec myProc 2    is ok

exec myProc @SomeIntValue    is ok
```

But,

```
exec myProc 2 + 2   is NOT ok.
```

So while a simple set, such as

```
DECLARE @i as int

Set @i = (2 + 2)

exec myProc @i
```

The above is ok, since you can ONLY pass a “value” to a stored procedure. You cannot pass an expression. In effect there is no evaluation or expression service available for the parameters you pass to a stored procedure.

So this issue is NOT limited to the use of sys.sp_addextendedproperty, nor is this a SPECIAL case of some kind. The issue you face applies to any kind of call and use of a stored procedure.

So in a set, or say select, you can use expressions, but not for passing values to a stored procedure.